# Comparing values in PHP multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, session-variables

SOLVED: Solution in answers.

I am building an eCommerce web page and I am having trouble with the cart. My problem is when the user adds an item to the cart and then decides to add that same item again, I'm unsure how to check if the quantity of the item in the cart exceeds the quantity of the item I have available in stock, which is kept track of in a mysql database.

If the cart is empty or hasn't been created yet this is how I add items to it:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart']) || count($_SESSION['cart']) < 1) {
  $_SESSION["cart"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => $itemQuantity));
}
```

Otherwise, I search through the entire cart to see if the item I am trying to add is already there, if it is, I update the quantity, if it isn't, I just push it into the array.

```
else {
  foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $eachItem) {
    $idx++;
    while(list($key, $value) = each($eachItem)) {
      if($key == "item_id" && $value == $pid) {
        array_splice($_SESSION["cart"], $idx-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => $eachItem['quantity'] + $itemQuantity)));
        $wasFound = true;
      }
    }
  }
  if($wasFound == false) {
    array_push($_SESSION["cart"], array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => $itemQuantity));
  }
}
```

and I already have access to how many of that item I have left in stock through a mysql_query:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id='$pid' LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $quantity = $row["quantity"];
    $name = $row["name"];
  }
```

Any ideas as to how to go about this?

My thoughts: I am almost positive that the code I need to make this work will be placed inside this if statement
`if($key == "item_id" && $value == $pid)`
and the check will need to use the quantity of that item currently in the cart, the quantity of that item I am trying to add to the cart, and the quantity of that item I have left in stock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after a good amount of guessing. I was over-thinking this problem greatly. Here's the answer:

```
if($eachItem['quantity'] + $itemQuantity > $quantity)
```

Comment: you should check if the requested number of items does not exceed the existing number in all places where you modify your cart data (3). Or also check at the very beginning if it makes even sence to search for the product. If user requests 10 items and you have only 4 it makes no sence to process the request (only if the logic works like "give me available amount of items or nothing happens") Btw. why don't you use the associative array for keeping the cart data? It would be easier to code, read and also faster then what you have now.

Comment: @AdamM This is the first time I've done anything like this so I'm still learning, [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL442E340A42191003) helped me out a bunch, which is the reason I used a multi-dimensional array. After searching around a bit, you are very right, an associative array would be much easier. Thanks for the tip!